# Get IP Address of Device on Same Network by Mac Address in React Native

Tags: react-native, raspberry-pi3

I have a react native project I'm working on where I need to make requests to a raspberry pi server using it's IP address. I need to connect to the raspberry pi regardless of if the IP address changes. I know the mac address of the Pi usually starts with either `b8:27:eb` or `dc:a6:32`. Using `arp -a | findstr /i "b8-27-eb dc:a6:32` as per this blog post https://www.shellhacks.com/find-raspberry-pi-ip-on-network-windows-macos-linux/ usually gives me the IP address of my raspberry pi. The project is strictly android, is there a way to achieve this in react native? If not in react native what native code could I use to accomplish this task?

Comment: Why dont you use dns for this?

Comment: I was just going on another mad google dash to find the answer and stumbled across zeroconf, not sure how it works though. Is it a better solution?

Comment: I tried using react-native-zeroconf to do lookup but doesn't seem to work. None of my registered events are firing.